# Move transformed HTML element to absolute position

Tags: javascript, graphics, transformation, css-transforms, affinetransform

I want to write a JavaScript function that moves CSS3 transformed (scaled, skewed, rotated) div elements to an absolute position in the container box. We are developing a canvas like application. I am using `getBoundingClientRect()` to find an absolute position and bounding-rect of the element. However, when I move this element to specified position it does not work because x and y position has translated.

Move to (0, 0):

[image]

```
// pseudocode I tried!

const matrix = getTransformationMatrix(elm); // get elements transormation matrix.
const pos = matrix.applyToPoint(0, 0); // find related coordiate of zeroth postion by applying element's matrix
tranlatePosition(elm, pos.x, pos.y);
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Please add the relevant part of your source code. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Updated the question with pseudocode, I tried similar code but it didn't work! Please check!